# cannot see subtitles in vlc

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles, delay

version: 3.0.11 vetinari (not quite sure what the means)
os: zorin ult 15 (ubuntu based)

these are the files

```
$ tree
.
├── Another 12.mkv
└── [ReinWeiss] Another - 12 [1080p CR-Modified].ass
```

the files are not corrupt in any way (checked redownloaded and checked hashes)

when I start vlc and drag n drop the files, everything works but the subtitles are awfully out of sync

`Dialogue: 0,0:00:11.08,0:00:12.61,Default,Tsujii,0000,0000,0000,,We've gotta get out of here!`

the first dialogue occurs on 1:41 in the movie file

I need a delay of 90 seconds, so applied the setting (+90.0) from `Tools > Track Synchronization > Subtitle Track Synchronization`

but after that the dialogues didn't showed up at all

I decreased the delay to +5.0 and as expected, the dialogues appeared right at 16 sec. the I increased it to +10.0 and it still worked. But +20.0 doesn't work. weird!

I then started vlc in the terminal to see if there's any error.
this is the output

```
$ vlc "Another 12.mkv" 
VLC media player 3.0.11 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11-0-gdc0c5ced72)
[000055cd2080fb10] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
QApplication: invalid style override 'adwaita' passed, ignoring it.
    Available styles: Breeze, Windows, Fusion
[00007f6214c0fbe0] main demux error: option sub-original-fps does not exist
[ass] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 1.7.2 (COMPLEX)
[ass] Using font provider fontconfig
[ass] fontselect: Using default font family: (Qlassik Bold, 700, 0) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/croscore/Arimo-Bold.ttf, 0, Arimo-Bold
[ass] fontselect: (Qlassik Bold, 700, 0) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/croscore/Arimo-Bold.ttf, 0, Arimo-Bold
[00007f6215c9ad40] main demux error: option sub-original-fps does not exist
[ass] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 1.7.2 (COMPLEX)
[ass] Using font provider fontconfig
[ass] fontselect: Using default font family: (Qlassik Bold, 700, 0) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/croscore/Arimo-Bold.ttf, 0, Arimo-Bold
[ass] fontselect: (Qlassik Bold, 700, 0) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/croscore/Arimo-Bold.ttf, 0, Arimo-Bold
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 100000, bound 9000000)
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 66522054636 for FFmpeg
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 100000, bound 9000000)
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 66549230604 for FFmpeg
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 35369001: no reference clock
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 43710001: no reference clock
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 100000, bound 9000000)
[00007f6214c39d30] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 66604836902 for FFmpeg
```

I thought it may be memory corruption or something, but there's nothing I can see and all other apps work fine except vlc freezes sometimes.

does anybody know what's going on ?

Comment: The video & subs files must be named identically except for the extension - then it should just find it automatically when you start the video. BTW, the VLC builds are all named after characters from Terry Pratchett's Discworld books. https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_CodeNames/

Comment: As @tetsujin says, so rename your subs file to `Another 12.ass`

Comment: I only have two files, so vlc automatically uses the ass file as subs with the mkv file, my issue was related to the vlc sunc feature (I got the solution, see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to my answer, vlc only supports sync delays in the range of -60.0 -> +60.0 seconds as pointed out by an anonymous redditor [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kodi/comments/72mu0j/why_the_subtitles_offset_correction_is_limited_to/)

(if your subtitles are so awfully out of sync, use some scripting or [sites like this](http://www.sync-subtitles.com/) to sync the subs lol)

edit: also, renaming the sub file to match video file is a good idea if you have a whole bunch of pirated anime files in the same directory

edit2: as @tetsujin said, the VLC builds are all named after characters from Terry Pratchett's Discworld books ([VLC version CodeNames](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_CodeNames/) :D)